# Unable to read configuration in impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am new to hybris. I am trying to use a `key=value` from `project.properties` in impex file.

I tried to copy the same `key=value` in my `local.properties` file as well. But it doesnt work.

**My code :**

**project.properties/ local.properties**

`mykey=myvalue`

**coredata.impex**

```
Insert_update User; uid[unique=true]; specialKey
;testuser;$mykey;
```

Where can I see any documentation for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in the right direction, just missing one intermediate step of importing property into impex macro key using correct processor.

**1 -** define your key in project or local properties file
`mykey=myvalue`

**2 -** Import above in impex macro using `ConfigPropertyImportProcesser`

```
GenericItem[processor=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.ConfigPropertyImportProcessor];pk[unique=true] 
$config-key=$mykey
```

**3 -** Run your impex with imported config macro

```
INSERT_UPDATE User; uid[unique=true]; specialKey
;testuser;$config-key;
```

> NOTE : Moving `key=value` from project.properties to local.properties will not make a difference. The later file only has precedence over the values defined in project.properties and helps you to define/maintain/override such pairs as per application/deployment environment needs.

Answer (score 1):

This question already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35266593/how-to-get-config-data-from-local-properties-to-impex) before.

Your impex would be

```
# Import config properties into impex macros
UPDATE GenericItem[processor=de.hybris.platform.commerceservices.impex.impl.ConfigPropertyImportProcessor];pk[unique=true]

Insert_update User; uid[unique=true]; specialKey
;testuser;$config-mykey;
```